# Linux to linux mount

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, samba, cifs

**Trying to mount a samba shared directory of a linux(SUSE) server to another linux(SUSE) server on the same network.**

> My scenarion is like below..

on `server-1` samba is configure like below and i can access the shared directory `/opt/direc-tory/` without any password or any issues from both Linux and Windows.

```
[software]
  comment = Viz Media Engine Client Software
  path = /opt/direc-tory/
  read only = yes
  public = yes
```

trying to `mount(cifs)` this directory on `server-2` like below..

```
mkdir -p /mnt/soft
server-2:/ # mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/opt/direc-tory/ /mnt/soft/
```

and getting this error message.

> Password:
>
> Retrying with upper case share name
>
> mount error(6): No such device or address
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

**It is asking for a password not sure for which user. Tried with all the system users like..**

```
mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/opt/direc-tory/ /mnt/soft/ -o user=user-1,password=passwd-1
```

**and getting this..**

> Retrying with upper case share name
>
> mount error(6): No such device or address
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

**any idea how can i mount that directory and which user password it's asking for ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not using NFS but CIFS. CIFS hides the underlying file system structure. The appropriate command to mount the “software” share is as follows:

```
mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/software /mnt/software
```